# Perform Memory Leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I am using Windows 7 Professional.
I have been given a task where i need to generate some System Level issues, so that a event should generate which we can see in Event viewer.

I am testing a product (Company Product* Can't disclose) consist of one dart which can check or create alert for a memory leak.

I wrote a simple code but i can't see any such event log in event viewer. Please suggest me any tool or any procedure through which at least an event should generate.

My code:

```
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      int * ptr = (int *) calloc (1000, sizeof(int));   // allocating 40 bytes 
                    // let sizeof int =  4 bytes)
      ptr = NULL;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `<stdlib.h>` to get the declaration of `calloc()` et al.  The 'allocating 40 bytes' comment doesn't match the code; at least one of them is wrong, therefore.  I don't know Windows 7 Professional, but I expect that it won't report a memory leak as such; it will report problems from programs crashing out of memory, which will require far more than 400 KiB of memory allocated to cause trouble, especially on 64-bit Windows and a machine with, say, 8 GiB of main memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the optimizer removed the call to `calloc` since the value returned from it is not being used at all. Add the following line after the call to `calloc` and before `ptr = NULL;`.

```
printf("%d\n", ptr[0]);
```

In other words, check the following program:

```
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
   for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      int * ptr = (int *) calloc (10, sizeof(int));     // allocating 40 bytes 
                    // let sizeof int =  4 bytes)
      printf("%d\n", ptr[0]);
      ptr = NULL;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would be easier to just use `volatile`, something like `int*volatile ptr`

Comment: @JensGustedt, it seems a compiler is allowed to optimize away `volatile` objects too as long as they are not global variables. See [unused volatile variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933314/unused-volatile-variable). Not sure how the compiler used by the OP deals with them.

Comment: If it is initialized dynamically, it is used. The compiler is not allowed to optimize the store to a `volatile`. If the compiler really would do that, it would be non conforming, but for a MS compiler you can expect anything. In that case I'd make it global in addition.

Comment: @Jens: If an identifier has block scope and internal linkage, and does not point to memory-mapped I/O or similar, I think the compiler can prove that it **cannot** have any unknown side effect, and can thus disregard the `volatile` qualifier.