# When can a volatile variable be optimized away completely?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, volatile

Consider this code example:

```
int main(void)
{
  volatile int a;
  static volatile int b;

  volatile int c;
  c = 20;
  static volatile int d;
  d = 30;

  volatile int e = 40;
  static volatile int f = 50;

  return 0;
}
```

Without `volatile` a compiler could optimize away all the variables since they are never read from.

I think `a` and `b` can be optimized away since they are completely unused, see [unused volatile variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933314/unused-volatile-variable).

I think `c` and `d` can not be removed since they are written to, and writes to volatile variables must actually happen. `e` should be equivalent to `c`.

GCC does not optimize away `f`, but it also does not emit any instruction to write to it. 50 is set in a data section. LLVM (clang) removes `f` completely.

Are these statements true?

1. A volatile variable can be optimized away if it is never accessed.
2. Initialization of a static or global variable does not count as access.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is volatile needed in c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246127/why-is-volatile-needed-in-c)

Comment: I think this question is more specific about how volatile variables may be optimized.

Comment: was `c = 30;` meant to read `d = 30;` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Writes to volatile variables (even automatic ones) count as observable behaviour.

C11 (N1570) 5.1.2.3/6:

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> — Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract
>   machine.
>
> — At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that
>   execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
>
> — The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in
>   7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output
>   appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to
>   a program waiting for input.
>
> This is the *observable behavior* of the program.

The question is: does *initialization* (`e`, `f`) count as an "access"? As pointed out by Sander de Dycker, 6.7.3 says:

> What constitutes an access to an object that has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined.

which means it's up to the compiler whether or not `e` and `f` can be optimized away - but this must be documented!

Comment: 6.7.3 says "What constitutes an access to an object that has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined.", which addresses your last paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking any volatile variable that is accessed (read or written to) cannot be optimized out according to the C Standard. The Standard says that an access to a volatile object may have unknown side-effects and that accesses to volatile object has to follow the rules of the C abstract machine (where all expressions are evaluated as specified by their semantics).

From the mighty Standard (emphasis mine):

> (C11, 6.7.3p7) "An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the
>   implementation **or have other unknown side effects**. Therefore **any expression referring
>   to such an object shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine**,
>   as described in 5.1.2.3."

Following that even a simple initialization of a variable should be considered as an access. Remember the `static` specifier also causes the object to be initialized (to `0`) and thus accessed.

Now compilers are known to behave differently with the volatile qualifier, and I guess a lot of them will just optimize out most of the volatile objects of your example program except the ones with the explicit assignment (`=`).

Comment: Note that declarations are not expressions

Comment: but it says a bit further : "What constitutes an access to an object that has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined." which explains the mentioned difference in behaviour between gcc and llvm.

Comment: If a volatile automatic variable does not have its address taken, that would suggest that a compiler could optimize out all instructions that would access it in the same situations where it could do so for a non-volatile variable *but* it could not move a side-effect which occurs after such an access to a point before it nor vice versa.